# Programmatically create constraints for UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UIViewController` which contains a `UIScrollView` which then contains a `UIImageView.` I've created a `UIButton` programmatically (my project does not contain a storyboard/nib).

I'd like the button to remain fixed to the upper-right corner of the screen but I cannot figure out how to manually create the proper constraint(s).

I thought the following would work but the button still isn't positioned correctly. Do I also need to do something in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`?

```
// Setup constraints, in viewDidLoad()
let viewDict = ["shareButton": self.shareButton!]
self.scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
                             withVisualFormat: "H:[shareButton]|", 
                                      options: [], 
                                      metrics: nil, 
                                        views: viewDict))

self.scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
                             withVisualFormat: "V:|[shareButton]",
                                      options: [], 
                                      metrics: nil, 
                                        views: viewDict))
```

Comment: Is `V:|[shareButton]` a typo? It is supposed to be `V:|[shareButton]|`.

Comment: What's the result of that code? Where the button will be? The button is a subview of the ViewController's view or of the scrollView?

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve this layout if the scroll view is the top-level view of your app. A constraint between a scroll view and a descendant of the scroll view always constrains the descandant within the scroll view's scrolling content. See [Technical Note TN2154 UIScrollView And Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) for more details. The tech note explains exactly what you need to do:

> Note that you can make a subview of the scroll view appear to float (not scroll) over the other scrolling content by creating constraints between the view and a view outside the scroll view’s subtree, such as the scroll view’s superview.

You need to arrange your view hierarchy like this:

```
+-- UIView (view controller's root view)
    |
    +-- UIScrollView
        |
        +-- UIImageView
        |
        +-- UIButton
```

or like this:

```
+-- UIView (view controller's root view)
    |
    +-- UIScrollView
    |   |
    |   +-- UIImageView
    |
    +-- UIButton
```

Then (with either of those arrangements) you can constrain the button to the root view, like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
    shareButton.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.trailingAnchor, constant:-8),
    shareButton.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor, constant: 8)
])
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. This is a [condensed version](https://gist.github.com/rmangino/ea99a98d85cbfa1e1eff9d02034cfca8) of my` viewDidLoad()` I haven't added any other constraints. Do you see the issue? TIA

Comment: You need to set `shareButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing everything in code, those two constraints are not enough to fully specify the placement of your UIIMageView, add at least a width and weight in those two constraints (e.g. modify the constraints you already have with `H:[shareButton(100)]|`).

Also, i recommend to disable the translation of the autoresizemask to constraints with `shareButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.

You don't need to do anything in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` for this layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this extension at the end of your class

```
extension UIView {


    func addCosntraintsWithFormat(format: String, views: UIView...) {

        var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()

        for (index, view) in views.enumerate() {
            let key = "v\(index)"
            viewsDictionary[key] = view
        }

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    }
}
```

and then you can add constraints like this

```
self.scrollView.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:[v0(\(YourWidthConstant))]|", views: shareButton)
self.scrollView.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0(\(YourHeightConstant))]", views: shareButton)
```

And the [source of this information is this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Xv1mJvwXok)

Comment: The source that i added contains relevant content at 35:00 minutes